# How do you use "top" to extract only the CPU usage and the process names (command) columns?

Tags: linux, bash, performance

I want only to extract the CPU usage column with the percentages and the process names from the output of the top command. Using this command: `top -b | awk '{print $NF}' > output.txt`, I can extract the last column from top and save into a file. However this solution is insufficient since COMMAND section can span multiple columns. How to extract and print CPU% and complete COMMAND section of top output ? The output format I need is like below.

```
%CPU  COMMAND
6.2   Xorg
6.2   gnome-terminal
6.2   top
0.0   init
0.0   kthreadd
0.0   ksoftirqd/0
0.0   kworker/0:0H
0.0   kworker/u:0H
0.0   migration/0
0.0   rcu_bh
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture the output of a top command in a file in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729720/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-top-command-in-a-file-in-linux)

Comment: Doesn't seems to be a duplicate. This question is about extracting and printing certain columns and suggested question is about dumping top result to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line or from within `top`?

If you're already in `top`, press <kbd>f</kbd> and toggle the columns you want to see.

Alternatively, you can use `ps`:

```
ps -eo %cpu,pid --sort -%cpu
```

Comment: Please not that ps's %CPU calculations take into account the whole period the process has been running. Top's implementation of %CPU gives you the CPU usage over a brief period of time (~1s default, configurable using -d)

Comment: busybox implementation of top gives very minimal options and does not have a toggle option. `top -b -d1 -n10 | tail -n +4 | awk '{ if ($7 != "0%") {for(i=7; i<NF; i++) printf "%s",$i OFS; if(NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}}'` if CPU% is 7th column and u want to print the command column too

Comment: CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running
   during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal, and it does not
   conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to.  CPU usage is
   unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.

Answer (score 1):

```
    top -stats "cpu,command"
```

If you want, extend it with PID or any other details. top -stats "pid, command,cpu"

Comment: Says `Unknown "t" option`.