# How to capture the output of a top command (for a specific process that will die) in a file

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I have a process `MYPID=18686` that I am monitoring with top.

```
top -b -n 1000 -d 5 -p $MYPID | tail -1 > log.txt
```

When the process dies, the output file is empty.

My end goal is just to record cpu usage over the lifetime of that process. Specifying `-n 1000 -d 5` is a cheap workaround that runs top for the expected lifetime of the process. The `tail -1` was to eliminate continually recording the top headers.

The answers to this question were helpful, but not a solution.
[How to capture the output of a top command in a file in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729720/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-top-command-in-a-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -1` does not produce the last line of each screen of output that `top` produces.  It produces only the last line of *all* the lines.

Try:

```
top -b -n 1000 -d 5 -p "$MYPID" | grep "$MYPID" > log.txt
```

This will collect into `log.txt` all the lines that mention the PID but none of the headers (assuming the PID doesn't appear on a header).

Note that `grep` is usually buffered.  This means that, if you check on `log.txt` during a run, it might be out of date.  With GNU `grep`, you can keep `log.txt` up to date with the `--line-buffered` option:

```
top -b -n 1000 -d 5 -p "$MYPID" | grep --line-buffered "$MYPID" > log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below options to save output in a file

- -b : batch operation mode
- -n : number of iterations
- -d : delay (interuption between each iteration; no need of this if you need 1 iteration )
- -f : output file ( only available in some versions, better off not using it then )

now having your purpose in mind, we can execute the following command to save the output in file :

```
top -b -n 1000 -d 5 -p $MYPID | grep -i "Cpu(s)" | head -c21 | cut -d ' ' -f3| cut -d '%' -f1 > state.log
```

if you wish to run your command in the background mode, without the possibility of being killed, when you logout the session, you may try below :

`nohup top-pid.sh &`